# Is it possible to automatically scrape articles from websites - Python & Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape, scraper

Trying to make a script to scrape one or two articles (article URLs only) from different websites, i was able to make a Python script that uses BeautifulSoup to get the website's HTML, find the website's Navbar menu via its Class name, and loop trough each website section, the problem is that each website has a different Class name or Xpath for the Navbar menu and its sections ..

Is there a way to make the script work for multiple websites with as little human intervention as possible ?

Any suggestions are more than welcome,

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Show us the code you've written so far so we can help get what you need.

Comment: it is possible only if the different websites share similar pattern in displaying the articles. Else the human intervention will be more which is almost equal to creating another scraper.

Comment: Did it, i have only needed to use Python and Selenium, the rest is just specific for our needs, it wasn't that complicated in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it, i have only needed to use Python and Selenium, an Xpath for the Navbar Elements for each website and another Xpath for all types of articles on the different website pages, saved everything on a database and the rest is just customized for our specific needs, it wasn't that complicated in the end, thanks for the help <3